# I can't access all webpages when connected to library's WiFi using Linux

Tags: networking, proxy

Whenever I'm connected to the local library's WiFi something strange happens.

If I'm using Windows - no matter which version or whose computer I'm using - and I connect to their network, upon launching any browser I'm prompted for a password.

The prompt window say something like "Provide password (...) 192.168.1.258:3583 (i guess that's the port, I can't remember very well)".
The password is publicly available at the library and upon inserting it I can access anything that I want.

Now, the curious thing is that when I'm on Linux (for instance I use Lubuntu, but that also happens in other Distros) or Android, I am not prompted for the password, but still I can connect to the network, but I can't access some pages, most notably the repositories of basically any distro (Debian, Ubuntu, Fedora, etc).

I can access https://packages.ubuntu.com/, for example, but upon clicking any package I get "ERROR The requested URL could not be retrieved" regardless of which browser I use or the mirror I choose. Due to that, issue apt-get update or apt-get install returns me a lot of errors and I can't download or update any packages.

I also noticed that any attempt to access pages using the FTP protocol or any attempt to browser a webserver's directories will give me the same error, but apart of that I can access most web pages.

Comment: Smells like the library's access system is misconfigured, since it's not redirecting your first Ubuntu web page connection to the login. If true (it's yet unproven) then there's very little Ubuntu can do about somebody else's broken system.

Comment: Makes sense. To me it also smells like the IT guys who've set up their network did some pretty slack job elsewhere too. Their wired connections are even more troublesome, son they tend to use WiFi on all computers. Apart of that I see no point in using this proxy or whatever it may be, since it doesn't block nor does it alter anything (for example, you can access porn from their WiFi).

Comment: I also tried just accessing their router's web interface but it not only has a weird  IP address (as if the gateway had been changed) but they also took care of changing its password :(